# Task scheduling No command 'app' found, but there are 16 similar ones

Tags: laravel

I was trying to schedule automated tasks using but nothing would happen

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /home/user/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /home/user/cron.log 2>&1
```

So I tried calling the job directly using the command below

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /home/user/laravel/artisan email:panelReport >> /home/user/cron.log 2>&1
```

After I enter the command above I keep this error in my `cron.log`

```
No command 'app' found, but there are 16 similar ones
app: command not found
```

If I run `php aritsan email:panelReport` I recieve the email just fine.

Kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\EmailPanelReport::class
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    $schedule
        ->command('email:panelReport')
        ->everyMinute()
}
```

EmailPanelReport.php

```
protected $signature = 'email:panelReport';
protected $description = 'Send out weekly report';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle()
{
    $panels = Orders::where('orders.prefix', 'P')->get();
    $columns = array ('Date', 'Order Number', 'Description');


    if ( !ini_get("auto_detect_line_endings")) {
        ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", '1');
    }

    try
    {

        $csv = Writer::createFromFileObject(new SplTempFileObject());
        $csv->insertOne($columns);
        $csv->insertAll($panels->toArray());

        $output = $csv->getContent();

        Mail::raw('See attached', function($message) use ($output)
        {
            $message->to('test@gmail.com');
            $message->subject("test");
            $message->attachData($output, 'test.csv', [
                'mime' => 'text/csv',
            ]);
        });

        $this->info("local");
    }
    catch (\Exception $ex)
    {
        $this->error($ex->getMessage());
        Mail::raw($ex->getMessage(), function($message)
        {
            $message->to('myemail@me.com');
        });
    }
}
```

System info:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- nginx/1.10.3
- php 7.1.7

Other ways I have tried

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /home/user/laravel/artisan email:panelReport >> /home/user/cron.log 2>&1
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php usr/share/nginx/www/laravel/artisan email:panelReport >> /home/user/cron.log 2>&1
* * * * *  /usr/bin/php /home/user/laravel/artisan email:panelReport >> /home/user/cron.log 2>&1
* * * * *  root /usr/bin/php /home/user/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /home/user/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: That error doesn't seem to coincide with your command or cron.  Where are you seeing that?

Comment: it appears in my log file as soon as I run the command

Comment: What are the contents of the command?

Comment: I updated the OP

Comment: Yeah, still doesn't make sense.  I feel like you're missing something in your post.  The error suggests you're running `php artisan app` but I don't see it.  I also don't know why you have Kernel.php and the schedule listed if you have a direct cronjob to run this command.

Comment: Originally I was trying to run ` * * * * root /php /project-path/artisan schedule:run >> /home/user/cron.log 2>&1` so that I could schedule all commands using laravel but it wasn't working so I was trying to do it directly

Comment: Actually when I run `php artisan app`, it returns a different message for me. `Command "app" is not defined.` Your `No command 'app' found, but there are 16 similar ones` seems to be a system message.   Check your system cron log.  I don't think that message is related to what you've posted here.

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule it writing your command using the `crontab` editor:

```sh
crontab -e
```

And paste your command on end of file, exit and save. The results should looks like this:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

To see your scheduled commands run:

```sh
crontab -l
```

I hope it helps!